# How to drag and drop from collectionView on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality in my app created especially for iPhone, it doesn't work starting from drag, so I still didn't try to drop because of this. It's a new feature for me, and I was trying to follow some training materials, all of them made for iPad for some reason. And if I try to run this training code(downloaded from course owner) on iPhone or in an iPhone simulator it doesn't work as well. Links on training materials:
1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/3121851-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-ios
2. https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-drag-drop-uicollectionview-cells-by-utilizing-dropdelegate-and-dragdelegate-6e3512327202

part of my code:

`collectionView.dragDelegate = self`

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        return dragItems(at: indexPath)
    }

    private func dragItems(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        if let itemCell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            as? CardCollectionViewCell,
            let image = itemCell.imageViewBack.image {
            let dragItem =
                UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider(object: image))
            dragItem.localObject = indexPath//image
            return [dragItem]
        }   else {
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re using the wrong initializer for `NSItemProvider`. That initializer is for types that conform to `NSItemProviderWriting`. It should be:

```
let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider(item: image, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is doesn't work too. By the way, I forgot to say that functions of drag are didn't called in the iPhone simulator if I will put a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Did you set `dragInteractionEnabled` to `true`?

Comment: Nope, this was the issue, thank you! I add             collectionView?.dragInteractionEnabled = true and now it works!